# Removing all Members in a Distribution Group

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to delete all the members of a distribution group without deleting the group as a while. I found another stackoverflow post where this seemed to do the trick:

```
foreach ($member in Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity Auto.test@company.com) 
{
  write-host $member
  Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity Auto.test@company.com -Member $member -Confirm:$False
}
```

However, it won't delete the users. It says this for every user it tries to delete...

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Member'. Cannot convert value "Smith, John" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.GeneralRecipientIdParameter". Error: "Cannot convert hashtable to 
an object of the following type: Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.GeneralRecipientIdParameter. Hashtable-to-Object conversion is not supported in restricted language mode or a Data section."

I'd think 'name' would be a a property remove-distributiongroupmember would take, but it doesn't seem like it wants to here.

So I tested this:

```
Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity Auto.Test@company.com -Member 'Smith, John'
```

And it works! It deletes the user just fine when I input the name manually. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just did it the old fashioned way with a while loop instead of trying to do it in one line.

```
$list = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DistributionGroup
$list | % {
   Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DistributionGroup -Member $_.Name -Confirm:$false
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's a bit late, bu trying to mess around with it today and the easiest possibility to remove all users from a DL is to work with it in AD. This might help someone at some point :)

So the code should be something like

```
Get-adgroup -identity $_.groupname -server "Domain" -properties *
Set-adgroup -identity $_.groupname -server "Domain" -Clear member
```

It's easier to play with the attributes in AD :D

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old and all of that - but there is an efficient way to do this. If you want to remove all members of a Distribution List, first update it with a single user, and then remove that user. The Update-DistributionGroupMember cmdlet do the trick, when you update with 1 user it removes everyone else:

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/update-distributiongroupmember?view=exchange-ps

> Use the Update-DistributionGroupMember cmdlet to replace all members
>   of distribution groups and mail-enabled security groups.

```
Update-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $groupname -Confirm:$false -Members myownuser@domain.com    
Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $groupname -Confirm:$false -Member myownuser@domain.com
```

2 steps and you are done

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a year later, but here is how I took your starting point and changed it slightly to work:

```
foreach ($member in (Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $groupname)) {
    Write-Host $member.primarySmtpAddress
    Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $groupname -Member $member.PrimarySmtpAddress -Confirm:$false
}
```

It is a foreach loop that goes through each member of a group, and then removes the user from the same group, but it uses the primary email address, instead of the member object, which may be where you were stuck. You could use Name instead of PrimarySmtpAddress property, but I think the email address is more readable.

I just used this code on a group in my O365 environment.  Thank you for the starting point, and I hope this contribution helps future readers of your question.