# Deleting ALL existing users from a list of Distribution Lists via powershell , Exhcange 2010

Tags: exchange-server

[Image of CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Ql4.png)

I have the following csv file ( lets name it del.csv )

I would like exchange to read all "Distribution Lists" on all rows under "column A" And remove ALL members from them.

Please advise this, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the data of CSV file via PowerShell:

[get specific cell value in csv file using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433562/get-specific-cell-value-in-csv-file-using-powershell)

And you could try this "Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "Technical Support" -Member "Jan Dryml" " please see the link :[Removing all Members in a Distribution Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484362/removing-all-members-in-a-distribution-group)

Updated:
Remove group directly.

```
$DGs=Import-Csv C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\DGS.csv    
$DGs | foreach {
$Group= $_.Group
IF ($Group) { 
Write-Output $Group
Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Group
Write-Output "Remove Success."
}

}
```

Or

```
$DGs=Import-Csv C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\DGS.csv 
$DGs | foreach {
$Group= $_.Group
IF ($Group) { 
Write-Output $Group
$list = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Group
$list | % {
   Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Group -Member $_.Name -Confirm:$false
   Write-Output "Remove Success."
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you fro your reply, I have been using this : [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/98f13482-d7b2-43a3-a1c3-a4ff536c5254/how-to-add-multiple-members-in-multiple-distribution-groups-by-using-powershell-script-office-365?forum=onlineservicesexchange) To add users using the same file. i want to have something similar, to remove all users maybe you have an idea of a script in mind ? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you My friend, you saved my a** :)